# Change Scala default class access modifier

Tags: scala, package, access-modifiers

Say I have bunch of Scala classes and I want to compile and package it to JAR.

I want to expose only some limited number of classes to external user of the JAR and "hide" any other classes.

The question: How can I achieve that without explicitly specifying *private* access modifier for classes to hide?

The problem is that in Scala class is *public* by default.

The ideal solution would be some Scala compiler option that changes default class modifier to *private*.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not possible, however you may have a change to achieve this with a compiler plugin. http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/140 However, to be honest, I'm not entirely sure this can be considered a good practice; I would suggest you consider simply using the `private` keyword so that your code is more portable and easier to reason about by people not familiar with it.

Comment: I can't think of any language with an equivalent of access modifiers which allows you to change the default with a compiler option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question. Scala provides `private` for exactly this usecase.